# "valid" pseudo class is not working on "required" email input if the input text format is NOT "email"

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I want the span in my label to move up when my input is on focus and valid mode, on email type input, when i write anything but an email format text, and then focus out of the input, the span comes back down, I just want it to stay up even if the format of my text is not "email".

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  }
  .form-group input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #595f6e;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  .form-group label {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
   .form-group label::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: -1px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #5fa8d3;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .form-group label .content-name {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      left: 0px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }


.form-group input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.form-group input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5fa8d3;
}
```

```html
    <form id="loginForm" action="{{ url_for('login.login') }}" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"
                                    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" required>
                                <label class="label-name">
                                    <span class="content-name">
                                        Name
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for. I _think_ you want the label to be translated regardless of whether it's valid or not, IF the input is not empty?

Comment: Yes, On both focus and valid it is supposed to be translated!

Comment: "valid" means that the input is not empty and that the pattern is matched. Your selector won't select the label if the input is **invalid**, which would be either empty or not matching the pattern.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that, But is there anyway to make it happen regardless of validity of the input?

Comment: There isn't a selector for "input has value" in CSS. `input[value=""]` only works if the input's value was set to exactly that before loading the page, and it doesn't respond to changes in the input's value. You'd have to use some sort of JavaScript to set something along the lines of an "is-dirty" class and use that in your CSS. That's pretty much what frameworks like Knockout.js do (no idea about Angular, React, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Consider `:focus` and `:placeholder-shown`. The first one will activate when you are at the input and the second one when there is at least some content. Don't forget to add an empty placeholder or the trick won't work

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #595f6e;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.form-group label {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.form-group label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5fa8d3;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.form-group label .content-name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.form-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) +.label-name .content-name,
.form-group input:focus +.label-name .content-name{
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5fa8d3;
}
```

```html
<form id="loginForm" action="{{ url_for('login.login') }}" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder=" " pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" required>
    <label class="label-name">
                                    <span class="content-name">
                                        Name
                                    </span>
                                </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Pretty good support for `:placeholder-shown`, too: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown - might need an extra selector for IE, if that support is needed.